# JQuery Function Call in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.save1= function(){
    var value = $("form#form1").serialize();
    send(value);
}

$.save2= function(){
    var value = $("form#form2").serialize();
    send(value);
}

$.save3= function(){
    var value= $("form#form3").serialize();
    send(value);
}

$.send= function(value){
    value = value + "&do=titlechange";
    $.ajax({
        url: "php_script.php",
        data: value,
        dataType: "json",
        type:"post",
        success: function(res){
            alert(res);     
        }
    });
}
```

I have 3 different form in same page. Also i have 3 different button, but i want to send values to same .php file. My code is above, but i could not call send function, in "save" functions. Save functions are binded buttons onclick.

Comment: OK, so what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `send(value);` with `$.send(value);` as you're creating function with variable name `$.send`.

```
$.save1= function(){
    var value = $("form#form1").serialize();
    $.send(value);
}

$.save2= function(){
    var value = $("form#form2").serialize();
    $.send(value);
}

$.save3= function(){
    var value= $("form#form3").serialize();
    $.send(value);
}

$.send= function(value){
    value = value + "&do=titlechange";
    $.ajax({
        url: "php_script.php",
        data: value,
        dataType: "json",
        type:"post",
        success: function(res){
            alert(res);     
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you buddy, it works :) i will accept in 11 min